# Using snprinf() do I need to account for the null bytes at the end of each concatenated string?

Tags: c, string-concatenation, mips32, printf

```
char str[33] = "";
snprintf(str, sizeof str, "%s%s%s%s", preg->opbits,preg->rsbits,preg->rtbits,preg->ibits);
char *instruction = &str[0]
```

I am trying to build a binary string from the different elements of a string representation of  a MIPS assembly instruction which is 32 bits long, where opbits is the 6 bit opcode, rsbits is the 5 bit number of the first source register, rtbits is the 5 bit number of the destination register for the immediate (i) type instruction and ibits represents the 16 bit integer value. I wish to concatenate these into a character array then assign a pointer to the first element of that array the pointer can be passed to an already defined function converting a number written as a string (in a specified base which is also passed to the strtoint function) to an integer value.

My main question is, do I need to account for the null bytes at the end of every string to be concatenated and second of all, would this work?

Comment: `6+6+6+16 = 34`, so maybe you should have `char str[35] = "";`, but you don't need to account for the 0-bytes of each part, only the one for the result.

Comment: I'd worry more about null characters inside the machine opcode data.  Also, do you mean to pack the various 6-bit fields? There's nothing in the `snprintf()` that's doing anything along those lines.

Comment: sorry, the register numbers are 5 bits long, not 6.

Comment: keep in mind though, If you're building up binary blobs, snprintf is not suitable as it deals with text.

Comment: the bit's are stored as a character string, not as numbers. So it is dealing with text. I need to print out the binary string first, then the string is to be passed into a function which I already have which takes the string and the base of the number represented in the string and returns an integer value, which I can then print out as a hex value.

Answer (score 3):

> My main question is, do I need to account for the null bytes at the
>   end of every string to be concatenated and second of all, would this
>   work?

No you do not have to count a null character for every sub string, you have to add only 1 null character for the result string concatenation

So if the length of your string result is 32 + 1 (null character) = 33

So your definition is OK if the length of your result conctaned string is 32

```
char str[33] = "";
```